# Dense_Rank with Case statement is not giving Rank with Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue while using Dense_Rank with CASE Statement. Below is the
sample table screenshot

[image]

So my requirement is two provide a Rank to every employee based on Emp_Dep_id

```
Req 1-->If Emp_Dep_id is same give same rank

Req 2-->If Emp_Dep_id is null then give same rank only when Emp_Joining_Date and Emp_Country is same
```

Below is the code to give rank

```
 Select case  
    when  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL   
    then   
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc,
  Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc,Emp.Emp_Country)  
   else  
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc)  
 end as   
 rnk ,*
 from Employee Emp with (nolock)
```

Below is Output-->

[image]

So,I am facing two issues-

1. Why Rank is skipping if same ranks is there ex- after second rank why sixth rank is coming next
2. I want to give rank basis of Emp_Joining_Date Currently it is behaving like firstly it is assigning rank if Emp_Dep_Id is not null after that it is continuing for Emp_Dep_Id is null.
   I want to get the rank based on latest Emp_Joining_Date means joining date with 2016 with null should come first

Thanks Guys for your valuable response,I fixed my issue by doing this way

```
 1. Step 1

    Select case  
    when  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL   
    then   
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Joining_Date,Emp.Emp_Country)  
    else  
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc)  
    end as   
    rnk ,*
    into #Emp_Output_Tbl
    from Employee Emp 

   Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_date desc


--Step 2

Select  distinct rnk,Emp_Joining_date into #Emp_New_Tbl  from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_date desc

Select * from #Emp_New_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_Date desc
Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_Date desc

--Step 3

Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl where rnk in(
Select TOP 5 rnk from #Emp_New_Tbl
)
order by Emp_Joining_Date desc

 **Output as per expectation**
```

[image]

I hope this is going to help

Comment: please go through Rank functions concept in Sql server .

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: @mohan111 Sure,I will do that but i want to know how can i handle two different partitions into one

Comment: Actually Dense rank will not have gaps 

for Example you have Emp_dep_id 23786 and 12376 .
count of 23786 is 3 and 12376 is 2 . so it gave 1 and 2 for all the 5 rows and again you have ordered with Emp_joining_date it have Rank 6 it gave duplicate date it gave 6 two times rest of all ranks came noraml

Comment: @mohan111 Actually rank 6 is expected because for Emp_dep_id with null is assigning because Emp_Country and Emp_joining_date is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks Guys for your valuable response,I fixed my issue by doing this way

  1. Step 1

  Select case  
 when  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL   
  then   
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Joining_Date,Emp.Emp_Country)  
  else  
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc)  
  end as   
  rnk ,*
  into #Emp_Output_Tbl
  from Employee Emp 

 Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_date desc


--Step 2

Select  distinct rnk,Emp_Joining_date into #Emp_New_Tbl  from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_date desc

Select * from #Emp_New_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_Date desc
Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl order by Emp_Joining_Date desc

--Step 3

  Select * from #Emp_Output_Tbl where rnk in(
  Select TOP 5 rnk from #Emp_New_Tbl
  )
   order by Emp_Joining_Date desc

 **Output as per expectation**
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this logic:
You want a single `dense_rank()`.  The trick is to get the logic into the `order by` clause.

I think this is what you want:

```
Select dense_rank() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id,
                                   (case when Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL then Emp.Emp_Joining_Date end) desc,
                                   (case when Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL then Emp.Emp_Country end) desc
                         )
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your query helped but i want to retreive on the basis of Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc .Issue i am facing is why dept_id with null is giving then then without null why rank is not assigned order by date

Answer (score 1):

The Dense rank is working as per the result set & the number of records in it. Please refer the link given 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx?

use the below query to know the result better. Also try to use order by after the SQL statement to order it properly.

```
Select 
DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc,
  Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc,Emp.Emp_Country),
DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc),
case  
    when  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id IS NULL   
    then   
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc,
  Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc,Emp.Emp_Country)  
   else  
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc)  
 end as   
 rnk ,*
 from Employee Emp with (nolock)
```

Comment: Thanks Midhun, your query helped but i want to retreive on the basis of Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc .Issue i am facing is why dept_id with null is giving then then without null why rank is not assigned order by date

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use the below query whether your requirement is met or not. I believe the dense range will operate as your requirement. You don't need to add a extra case statement. Only thing you need to specify is the order of the column. It automatically handle as you required.

```
 Select    
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by  Emp.Emp_Dep_Id desc,Emp.Emp_Joining_Date desc,Emp.Emp_Country)  as  rnk ,*
 from Employee Emp with (nolock)
```

> Req 1-->If Emp_Dep_id is same give same rank
>
> Req 2-->If Emp_Dep_id is null then give same rank only when
>   Emp_Joining_Date and Emp_Country is same